# Optimize a search & insert text to a gcode file

Tags: javascript

I am trying to process a *.gcode file (plain text) that is currently 2.5mb in size, but could be as large as 50mb.  In the process it searches for the indexOf a key and then it finds the following new line character to insert the specific script needed to modify the gcode.  For a 2.5mb file it takes nearly 6 seconds to process this request. I'd like to shorten this process if possible and test it against a 50mb file.
Thx for any input.

```
var loc_array = [2.500, 10.000];
var pos = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < loc_array.length;i++){
    //Find Line
     var p = gcode.indexOf("END_LAYER_OBJECT z="+loc_array[i], pos);
     if (p != -1){
         //Go to the following line and insert String
         p = gcode.indexOf("\n", p);
         gcode = gcode.slice(0, p)+ "G28 X\nM117\nM0\nG28 X"+gcode.slice(p);
         pos = p;
     }
}
```

Comment: I run a separate script to sort the loc_array.  So that I can reduce the amount of text that is searched through via indexOf.

Comment: is this run on node ? you can consider using the fs api and spawn some async seek and check. You would have to assemble results in the end. Do you think that would work ?

Comment: No node, I was planning on running this script on clientside, so that I could prevent the overhead of moving any amount of data.